# VS Code compiling on opening a new file

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code

Since last week or so, when I am on ng serve, VS Code compile the app again when I open existing files in the project.

In theory, the compile should just happen when I save a file and not by opening a file.

Other developers in the team aren't facing the same issue, I have tried to disable all extension we have with the exception of Nx Console and Material Icon Theme. Even so, the behavior persists, which indicates that is not an extension issue.

Do anyone knows what is triggering the compile of app, or maybe some way to identify why it's being triggered?

The answer I'm looking for is how to stop that behavior, I want the compile process to be triggered only when I save changes to a file, and not everytime I open an existing one.

Comment: have you update a visual studio code.?

Comment: If you question is about my VS Code, I am running latest version 1.43.2.
If you question is to check if I changed code, no, I recompiles as soon as I open a existing file. I won't recompile If I create a new file (just a New file, not saving it)

Comment: if you create a new file or component then it will re-compile automactically

Comment: Yes, that is the standard behavior. But it should not re-compile when you open an existing file, which is the issue I'm describing.

Comment: uninstall all extension and restart your visual studio code to change the effect after re-run the project and check

Comment: Already tried it.

Comment: @EstevaoSantiago: Have you ever found a solution? I'm currently facing the exact same issue and its driving me crazy.

Comment: @Tobias Never found the root cause, but I was able to bypass the issue by setting the poll. On the computer with the issue, I run `ng serve --poll 5000`. The 5000 is just the amount of seconds which the rebuild should be triggered after the change is detected. I found the --poll on https://angular.io/cli/serve and gave it a try.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone with the above issue, to the moment of this, I have neither a solution nor the root cause.

But I did found a way to bypass the problem using `ng serve --poll 5000`. Found that on https://angular.io/cli/serve

From what I found over the interwebs, it basically shifts who is responsible for detecting file changes. The 5000 is just the amount of seconds before triggering the rebuild. I have been using a couple of months now (maybe more) and did not notice any serious tradeoffs so far.

Answer (score -1):

maybe you should disable/off autosave onWindowChange that make your project compiling when you open the others files...
manage -> setting : files autosave

Comment: Only reference I found for `onWindowChange`is related to Text Editor > Files > Auto Save, and that option is already set to off